# How to catch AuthenticationFailedException that appeared in ImapMailReceiver

Tags: java, spring-integration-dsl

```
private IntegrationFlowRegistration getIntegrationFlowRegistration(){
  IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(createImapMailReceiver(imapUrl))
                    .autoStartup(true)
            )
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
    return this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
```

}

I create dynamically IntegrationFlowRegistration for different customers and sometimes credentials are incorrect. I would like to catch AuthenticationFailedException and log it but can't find a way to catch it. Could you please give me a hint of how it can't be done? I read DSL documentation but didn't find a way or good example there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `ApplicationListener<ImapIdleExceptionEvent>` bean, or an `@EventListener` method that receives that event type.

```java
@EventListener
public void imap(ImapIdleExceptionEvent event) {
...
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#imap-idle-and-lost-connections

> Beginning with the 3.0 release, the IMAP idle adapter emits application events (specifically `ImapIdleExceptionEvent` instances) when exceptions occur. This allows applications to detect and act on those exceptions. You can obtain the events by using an `<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter>` or any ApplicationListener configured to receive an ImapIdleExceptionEvent or one of its super classes.